# Installing bower is throwing errors

Tags: npm, installation, bower

I can't seem to install bower properly. I don't know what's wrong, but it keeps throwing these errors. Can someone help?

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/Jeanwoo/.npm/bower/1.4.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Jeanwoo/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the command you're running is `npm install -g bower` (to install Bower globally on your machine).

The error

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

...makes me think you should try running as root:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

And then input your password and it should install. If not, what is the command you're running?

Comment: Thanks that actually did the trick. I forgot the sudo was the one to login to root